# Launch Java with a specific argument each time

Tags: java, bash

I have a program which allows me to define the java executable (`/usr/bin/java`), but does not allow me to add specific arguments to the executable.

I want to be able to run Java with a specific argument each time in order to enable Security Manager.

So far, I have tried to add the argument after `/usr/bin/java`, so it looks like

```
java=/usr/bin/java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/home/java.policy
```

That did not work as the program probably checks to see if a file exists. Another way I tried was to make a bash script called `java` which contained:

```
/usr/bin/java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/home/java.policy $*
```

I then set the java path to `/home/java` (Location of my script). That however did not work either. Is there some sort of way I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: "I have a program" what program?

Comment: Have you tried `java="/usr/bin/java -D....."` (note the double quotes around the whole java command)?

Comment: You are getting an exception or a shell error message? Can you add the exact message to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your java call in a shell script `java.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/home/java.policy $@
```

Change permissions with `chmod u+x java.sh`, then call your program with `java=./java.sh` (adapt path for your script as needed).

#### Notes about executable bit and shebang line

Both the shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`) and execute permission are important here. Without them, system calls of the `exec*` family will fail because the kernel does not know what to do with the file or because execution is rejected due to the missing executable bit.

This is different when run directly from a shell (`./java.sh`), because most shells have some compatibility feature for that case so they will run a script in a shell if `exec*` fails. The execute permission must be set though.

The only case where neither is needed is if you give your script as argument to the shell: `bash java.sh`.

Comment: @CeleStyga: Yes, both the shebang and execute permission are needed when calling a script without a parent shell (I guess your Java program calls something like `execve()` and not `system()` which would pass the call to a shell). I've added a paragraph with some details.

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach would be ok, but your problem is likely to be that your Multicraft application is not finding your script. More so, it's the environment of your web server (Apache?) that may need to have PATH altered to be able to find your java wrapper script.